# Javascript to get class or Id of that div which is largest in number?

Tags: javascript

I want javascript to get `id` of that `div` which has largest number. Here is example.

```
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="3"></div>
<div class="41"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
```

now it should get the largest `id` or `class` of the `div` means function have to determine which is largest and save it in a variable.

```
var id = largestdivnumber
```

Thanks

Comment: IDs cannot be numeric (at least not in HTML 4, thanks @Alex), so this approach will not work. I would use a different attribute and then maybe use jQuery to walk through every element with that attribute, comparing the values in a loop.

Comment: then man can i add a class which is numeric ? if yes, then how can i get the largest class?

Comment: For what do you need that? You should not need to enumerate your elements in the markup

Comment: Numeric IDs are perfectly fine in HTML5, is that what your using? if not prefix with a letter, loop, read id ignoring the prefix, parseint the rest and capture the greatest

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function (){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var maxId = 0;
    var max = 0;
    for (var i =0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        var id = parseInt(elements[i].id);
        if (id > maxId)
        {
            maxId = id;
            max = i;
        }
    }

    // Element with max id.
    console.log(elements[max]);
};
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/kdGCm/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('div').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
})[0];
```

Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/kdGCm/6/)

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't sort in `O(n log n)` but just reduce in `O(n)`

Comment: yeah this is working perfect but the code you used is difficult for me to understand.

Comment: I never used that map or sort functions before. I just use Jquery for ajax, fadeIn, fadeOut and this type of basic functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function (){
  max_id = 0
  $.each($("div"), function(i, e){
    id_val  = $(e).attr("id")
    id_num = parseInt(id_val)
    if (!isNan(id_num)){
      if (id_num > max_id){
         max_id = id_num
      }
    }
  })
  element_you_need = $("#"+max_id)
}
```

You will need Jquery for this to work

Comment: There is no jQuery tag in question.

Comment: Why do you use `window.onload` while you use jQuery?